# Where to find Android benchmarks results?

Tags: performance

I am looking for a site where to find Android benchmark results for the different smartphones and android builds.

Answer (score 2):

http://smartphonebenchmarks.com/

That link is unverified nor do I know how scientific any of it is. But it was about all I could fine for multiple devices.